# margin doesnt work after a floating div

Tags: css, html, css-float, margin

In the code bellow, why the blue div doesnt got the margin-top?
I put the clear:both, but it seens useless.

Thanks.

```
<div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left; background-color: red">aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa| 
</div>

<div style="width: 200px; float: right; background-color: red"> a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a aa dasd ada da a </div>    
</div>

<div style="clear: both; width: 200px; background-color: blue; margin-top: 100px; height: 100%">ccccccccccs </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYLqA/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing in a wrong way, use this line before the blue `div`

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHM5G/)

> Tip: I would suggest you to wrap the floated elements inside a wrapper
>   and self clear that wrapper instead of keeping the floated divs without any container, also > there are 2 stray tags which I've removed

If you want to self clear an element

```
<div class="wrapper clear">
  <div class="floated1"></div>
  <div class="floated2"></div>
</div>
<div class="another_div_with_margin_top"></div>

.clear_self:after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: table;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the cleared wrapper around the floated elements is the best solution. Using an extra div for clearing is best avoided, as it's keep the HTML clear of presentational markup. The reason the original top margin didn't work is that it slips under the floated divs. It would only start to work if the margin were greater than the height of the tallest floated div.

Answer (score 0):

set the

```
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
```

in the top containing div style.
it will solve your issue.

[jsFiddle File Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nYLqA/21/)